# Silverlight and web services

Tags: web-services, silverlight-4.0

I am new to silverlight and i am having troubles connecting with a web service: wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx . I am not sure what the easiest way is to do this and every tutorial on the internet is throwing me in a new direction. Can somebody put a simple walkthrough of what i have to do to get the xml data into my silverlight project?

Thanks very much!

As of now i have the web service referenced in my silverlight project and:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ServiceReference1.WeatherSoapClient service = new ServiceReference1.WeatherSoapClient();
            service.GetCityForecastByZIPCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.GetCityForecastByZIPCompletedEventArgs>(service_GetCityForecastByZIPCompleted);

            service.GetCityForecastByZIPAsync("54481");
        }

        public void service_GetCityForecastByZIPCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetCityForecastByZIPCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("done: " + e.Result);
        }
```

But e.result only returns "Lab_09.ServiceRe3ference1.ForecastReturn"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your XML data is in `e.Result`. You can put a break point on `e.Result` and explore the XML response.

For example, `MessageBox.Show(e.Result.City);` displays Stevens Point.

Likewise, `MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ForecastResult[0].Temperatures.DaytimeHigh.ToString());` will show the the first `days(ForcastResult[0])` daytime high.

Comment: What would be the easiest way to populate this into a Grid (one column for each day)?